# Given the ranks of $Q$ and $QP$, how to find the rank of $P$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two real matrices of size $4\times6$ and $5\times4$, respectively . If $\operatorname{rank} Q = 4$ and $\operatorname{rank} QP = 2$, what is the rank of $P$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By Sylvester’s rank inequality,

$$\operatorname{rank}(P)+\operatorname{rank}(Q)-4 \leq \operatorname{rank}(QP)$$

which implies that 
$$\operatorname{rank}(P) \leq \operatorname{rank}(QP)=2$$

Can you find a lower bound for $\operatorname{rank}(P)$?

Comment: @user1551 The second line comes from the first line. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant now. I thought you were quoting two separate inequalities.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for checking. Let's hope OP can figure out the lower bound. =)

Comment: Can we do this : Since rank Q = 4,where Q is a 5*4 matrix , then rank QP = rank P and so rank P = 2...but here shouldn't Q be non singular,which is not possible as Q is not a square matrix ?

Comment: Yes, it is due to $Q$ has full column rank, hence $rank(QP)=rank(P)$. you are right that $Q$ can't be non singular as it is not a square matrix.

Comment: Please note that when you are writing an operation on an argument, say rank(P), when formatting in Mathjax, please use `\operatorname{rank}(P)` with renders as follows: $\operatorname{rank}(P)$ which is much more appropriate than `rank(P)`: $rank P$.

Comment: Thank you for the tips!